# Twig using without Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I don't find any information about using twig without Symfony.
I want to use twig in my custom web page without symfony framework.
Is it possible?

Comment: Did you use composer?

Comment: yes, I just downloaded twig with cmd. But how use twig in my page??

Comment: This perfectly clear question has a perfectly fine answer. If we reopen it the OP can accept the answer.

Answer (score 28):

To give you a runnable sample:

1. Install Twig in empty project:

   ```
    composer require "twig/twig:^3.0"
   ```
2. Create the following "test.php" file:

   ```
   <?php

     require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

     $loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader('./templates');
     $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);

     echo $twig->render('demo.twig', ['name' => 'Fabien']);
   ```
3. Create the view:

   ```
    mkdir templates
    cd templates
    echo "Hello, {{ name }}!" > demo.twig
   ```
4. Run the demo:

   ```
    cd ..
    php test.php
   ```

Comment: I did like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLweQpE59oU&index=2&list=PLfdtiltiRHWEDq2ZY4sK5551_7ePE-SI8 it is very similar as yours, but i get an error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with message 'The "views" directory does not exist.' in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\Twig\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php:94 Stack trace: #0 and so on..

Comment: Thanks for perfect answer to legitimate question, Alain Tiemblo. 
The example actually works too. @Zhinuz, it's probably too late for helping you, but you probably just named your folder differently (or used wrong path in your test.php file), since your code complains about "views" folder not existing.

Comment: exact same problem here as mentioned by @zhinyz in comment section

Comment: For all previous comments - the answer has been updated and tested. I confirm that it works